# Is this use of ConcurrentDictionary truly thread safe?

Tags: f#, hash-map

I'm working on some teaching examples showing the perils of accessing the Dictionary class concurrently.  In the code below each function is designed to do a word count across a number of files.  (This isn't the best way of doing the count but it's there to make a point about Dictionary.)

The first example, using a Dictionary and no parallelism works fine.

The second example, using a Dictionary and Array.parallel can fail with an exception and also produces different results each time.  This is deliberate and is there to make the point.

The final example uses ConcurrentDictionary and seems to me to work fine.  My concern is: given this uses a delegate to do the count addition, is this version genuinely thread safe?

```
// Simple version:
let WordCount dirPath wildCard =

   let wordCounts = Dictionary<string, int>()

   let ProcessFile fileName =
      let text = File.ReadAllText(fileName)

      text.Split([|'.'; ' '; '\r'|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
      |> Array.map (fun w -> w.Trim())
      |> Array.filter (fun w -> w.Length > 2)
      |> Array.iter (fun w -> 
         let ok, count = wordCounts.TryGetValue(w)
         if ok then
            wordCounts.[w] <- count+1
         else
            wordCounts.[w] <- 1)

   Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath, wildCard)
   |> Seq.iter ProcessFile

   wordCounts
   // |> Seq.sumBy (fun kv -> kv.Value)
   |> Seq.sortBy (fun kv -> -kv.Value)

// Naive concurrent version:
let WordCount2 dirPath wildCard =

   let wordCounts = Dictionary<string, int>()

   let ProcessFile fileName =
      let text = File.ReadAllText(fileName)

      text.Split([|'.'; ' '; '\r'|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
      |> Array.map (fun w -> w.Trim())
      |> Array.filter (fun w -> w.Length > 2)
      |> Array.iter (fun w -> 
         let ok, count = wordCounts.TryGetValue(w)
         if ok then
            wordCounts.[w] <- count+1
         else
            wordCounts.[w] <- 1)

   Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath, wildCard)
   |> Array.ofSeq
   |> Array.Parallel.iter ProcessFile

   wordCounts   
   |> Seq.sumBy (fun kv -> kv.Value)
   // |> Seq.sortBy (fun kv -> -kv.Value)

// Safe concurrent version:
let WordCount3 dirPath wildCard =

   let wordCounts = ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>()

   let ProcessFile fileName =
      let text = File.ReadAllText(fileName)

      text.Split([|'.'; ' '; '\r'|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
      |> Array.map (fun w -> w.Trim())
      |> Array.filter (fun w -> w.Length > 2)
      |> Array.iter (fun w -> wordCounts.AddOrUpdate(w, 1, (fun _ count -> count+1 )) |> ignore)

   Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath, wildCard)
   |> Array.ofSeq
   |> Array.Parallel.iter ProcessFile

   wordCounts 
   |> Seq.sumBy (fun kv -> kv.Value)
   // |> Seq.sortBy (fun kv -> -kv.Value)
```

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ it be thread-safe? Isn't that what `ConcurrentDictionary` is for?

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary` provides thread-safety through atomic operations, so you shouldn't call `ContainsKey` followed by `Item`, you should call `TryGetValue`. That's why it has methods like `GetOrAdd` and `AddOrUpdate` that the regular `Dictionary` doesn't.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I know. All I'm saying is that it makes sense to ask “Am I using `ConcurrentDictionary` correctly?” Because you *can* use it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just used your original code (`TryGetValue` followed by an indexer set) with `ConcurrentDictionary`, then that wouldn't be thread-safe.

But you're using the `AddOrUpdate` method instead, which is guaranteed to be thread-safe (i.e. atomic), so this use is thread-safe.

---

One other nitpick:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath, wildCard)
|> Array.ofSeq
```

If you don't actually want `seq`, but an array, `Directory` has a method just for that: [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f).

Comment: AddOrUpdate is thread-safe (so it won't become internally corrupt), but not atomic (i.e it's basically a TryAdd followed by a TryUpdate. TryAdd and TryUpdate are atomic, but AddOrUpdate itself isn't. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-add-and-remove-items#example, quote underneath the example.